# How can you find multiple answers for vectors a and v in parametric vector form given by the Cartesian equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametric

For example you have the cartesian equation:

```
(x-2)/-2 = y/3 = (z-1)/3
```

One possible choice for a is the vector <2, 0, 1>. How can you find a different possible vector of a. I understand that another one for v is any scalar multiple of it as the pvf is a span right?

Note: Sorry for the maths not being typed well this is my first post and i am unsure how to type it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the line doesn't go through the origin, you can't just scale up the vectors.

Instead, notice that you can freely set any one of the variables, e.g. $x$, and that will restrict the other values.

For example, set $x = p$, then you get $\frac{p - 2}{-2} = \frac{y}{3} \implies y = 3(1 - \frac{p}{2})$. Similarly, you'll be able to get an expression for $z$ in terms of $p$, so the possible vectors are $a = \langle p, 3(1 - \frac{p}{2}), ???\rangle$ where $???$ is whatever you get for $z$. To choose a particular value for $a$, just set $p$ to an actual value like 1 or -1.